# C# Int64Converter cannot convert from System.Int64 error when converting DataRow to type T

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to return all records from a SQL table as IEnumerable e.g. Email Account table results to an Enumerable Collection of EmailAccount.  I use a method called SelectAll that executes a SQL script and then returns the DataTable as Enumerable.

The issue is when trying to convert some columns from the table of type Int64 to an object of T with a matching property of type long using GetItem method, I get an error of '**Int64Converter cannot convert from System.Int64**' at line '**pro.SetValue(obj, typeConverter.ConvertFrom(dr[column.ColumnName]), null);**'.

Any suggestions on how I can convert the Int64 value from the table result to a property of long?

```
public void Test()
{
    var results = SelectAll<EmailAccount>();
    ....
}

public class EmailAccount
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImapEnum ImapType { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll<T>() where T : new()
{
    var tableName = "EmailAccount"; // TableName<T>();

    var results = ExecuteReader($"SELECT * FROM {tableName};");

    if (results == null || results.Rows.Count == 0) return null;

    return results.AsEnumerable().Select(GetItem<T>);
}

private static T GetItem<T>(DataRow dr)
{
    var temp = typeof(T);
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

    foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)
    {
        foreach (var pro in temp.GetProperties())
        {
            if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName)
            {
                if (pro.PropertyType == typeof(Enum) || pro.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
                {
                    pro.SetValue(obj, Enum<StringComparison>.ToObject(dr[column.ColumnName]), null);
                }
                else
                {
                    var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(pro.PropertyType);
                    pro.SetValue(obj, typeConverter.ConvertFrom(dr[column.ColumnName]), null);
                }                    
            }                        
            else
                continue;
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TypeConverter` class is usually used to convert between `T` and `string`. In your case `dr[column.ColumnName]` where `column.ColumnName` is `Id` the result *is* allready a `long` so no converting or casting is needed. The need for a `TypeConverter` will arise, if your class contains a type, that is not supported by your Database. This will be very likely any non primitive Type. As a solution to your problem, you might use:

```
var value = dr[column.ColumnName];

if (pro.PropertyType == typeof(Enum) || pro.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
{
    pro.SetValue(obj, Enum<StringComparison>.ToObject(value), null);
}  
else if(prop.PropertyType().IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType())
{
    pro.SetValue(obj, value);
}
else
{
    var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(pro.PropertyType);
    pro.SetValue(obj, typeConverter.ConvertFrom(value), null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, adding the IsAssignableFrom check worked.

Answer (score 3):

The Int64Converter can act on only string objects.

> This converter can only convert a 64-bit signed integer object to and from a string
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.int64converter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks

So I will suggest you to use this code -

```
pro.SetValue(obj, typeConverter.ConvertFrom(dr[column.ColumnName].ToString()), null);
```

Comment: Didn't realise that. That helped with some of the data scenarios thank you.